# OpenSea 3.1 API Validation Errors

Tags: node.js, api, openapi, opensea, opensea-api

I believe OS's OpenApi definition is invalid at version `v1.0#1e41yo45l0vihg6s`. When I attempt to use it from Node using the `api` package in my project I get validation errors. Simple steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Node project and initialize

   ```
    mkdir os-api-test
    cd os-api-test
    npm init
   ```
2. Per OS [docs/examples](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-contract), install the `api` package:

   ```
    npm install api --save
   ```
3. Create file `index.js` and populate it with the example code (address and API key omitted here, but they're valid and I can use them via the API UI):

   ```
    const sdk = require('api')('@opensea/v1.0#1e41yo45l0vihg6s');

    sdk['retrieving-a-single-contract']({
      asset_contract_address: 'REDACTED',
      'X-API-KEY': 'REDACTED'
    })
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
   ```
4. Run the example

   ```
   node index.js
   ```
5. Output:

[image]

Looking at the API definition [here](https://dash.readme.io/api/v1/api-registry/1e41yo45l0vihg6s) and specifically at the `/assets/get` path, there are indeed duplicate `owner` parameters:

> ```
>   "parameters": [
>       {
>         "name": "owner",
>         "in": "query",
>         "description": "The address of the owner of the assets",
>         "schema": {
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>       },
>       ...
>       {
>         "name": "owner",
>         "in": "query",
>         "schema": {
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>       }
>       ...
> ```

And per the [OpenApi 3.1 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#path-item-object), in reference to the path item object:

> A list of parameters that are applicable for all the operations described under this path. These parameters can be overridden at the operation level, but cannot be removed there. **The list MUST NOT include duplicated parameters**.

Obviously I can't change the API definition but is there any way to work around this, perhaps via configuration of the `api` package?  I dug into its code but nothing jumped out at me. It's surprising that such a widely used API would have a bug that renders it unusable, yet I can't find any other mentions of it.  I realize I may be able to use fetch to hit the API directly but I'd like to use the `api` package.

Interestingly the [testnet API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-contract-testnets) does not suffer from this same bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for surfacing this. We had documented the `owner` parameter twice, which led to this issue. It is fixed it now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).